# Reset objects collision so OnCollisionEnter triggers again

Tags: unity-game-engine

We have an unusual use case. Let's say you have 2 objects that is touching. This will trigger `OnCollisionEnter`. Now we change ownership of one of them (It's a multiplayer VR game). Now we need to also assign ownership to all touching items to get local physics to look nice.

The naive brute force way would be to use `OnCollisionStay` and do the ownership check every frame. But its naive and increased frame time.

There must be a way of "resetting" the objects collision when taking ownership, so the `OnCollisionEnter` triggers again for all items it touches?

Comment: I really don't know if it would work, but maybe, simply disabling and enabling back the gameobject would work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe track all items currently touching an item in a list.

Add new item in `OnCollisionEnter`.

Remove item in `OnCollisionExit`.

Then you can loop thorugh all currently touching items to change the owner

Comment: But It must be away of letting the engine reset the collision state?

Comment: Have you tried

collider.enabled = false;

and then 

collider.enabled = true;

right after?

EDIT: It should be the collider and not collision

Comment: Yepp,thats the first I tried, have not tried gameobject.setActive as suggested above. But I think one frame will have to pass between the two. And thats not good enough for me. However. We might need to use onstay anyway, because the problem is a item can be dragged by another item and when the item being dragged by another item collides with a third item we need to proxy the ownership through all these items :D pretty complex usercase, here is a video I made showcasing the problem, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STxYseRabQ8

Comment: Cant check the video right now.

But one last suggestion:

Give the objects a boolean like "ownerChanged" and set it to true when the owner is changed.
Then you could do:

`OnCollisionStay()
{
   if(ownerChanged)
   {
      //DO STUFF ONLY IF OWNER CHANGED
   }


}`

This will check every frame, but will only go on if the owner really changed